# How do I post to a REST service using RestTemplate in Spring

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

How do I post to a REST service using RestTemplate. I have the following RESTful web service and I would like to use RestTemplate to post a new user object to to?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
class APIController
{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(APIController.class);

    private MappingJacksonJsonView  jsonView = new MappingJacksonJsonView();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public User updateCustomer(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody User user) {

        logger.debug("I am in the controller and got user name: " + user.toString());
        return user;
    }
}
```

How do I change the following code to post the user object?

```
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate(commons);
    rt.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    rt.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

    URI uri = new URI("http://" + mRESTServer.getHost() + ":8080/springmvc-rest-secured-test/api/2");

    User u = new User();
    u.setName("Johnathan M Smith");
    u.setUser("JMS");


    User returns = rt.postForObject(uri, u, User.class);

    LOGGER.debug("User:  " + u.toString());
```

Here is the error and output I am getting:

```
    2013-06-18 08:11:36,819 [main] ERROR com.johnathanmarksmith.springresttemplate.Main - error:  <html><head><title>JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final</h3></body></html>
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@71290aac; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.. the programmer that coded the User Object for the RESTful Service did not have

```
public User()
{
}
```

once that was added to the user object everything works.. it was NOT a client issue..**it was on the server side**

Answer (score 0):

I noticed at least two problems:

**The first one** is that you are sending your request to a wrong url. The request mapping of our controller method the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST )
```

But you send to request to url:

```
"http://" + mRESTServer.getHost() + ":8080/springmvc-rest-secured-test/json/user/2"
```

You might want to remove the string 'json' from the path.

**The second problem** is that your controller method returns an `User` object but when you call the `postForObject()` method of the `RestTemplate` class, you state that the return type of your controller method is `String`.

You should change the line:

```
String returns = rt.postForObject(uri, u, String.class);
```

to:

```
User returns = rt.postForObject(uri, u, User.class);
```

[See the Javadoc of the RestTemplate class for more details about this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Comment: i made the changes you requested and posted the output

Comment: Updated my answer based on the log output. I totally missed the first problem when I answered to your question for the first time. Sorry about that.

Comment: Have you tried removing the StringHttpMessageConverter from the RestTemplate?

Comment: I got it.. the programmer that coded the User Object for the RESTful Service did not have

public User()
{
}